# Join two tables using a loop and SUM

Tags: sql, t-sql, join

I have a table (distance_travelled) with the columns 
Primary Key | VehicleName | StartDate | Enddate | Total Distance

[image: Table distance_Travelled]

another table called Idling with columns 
Vehicle Name | Duration | Timestamp 
[image: Idling Table]

I have taken steps to get far but best way to ask the question is from scratch 
i want the output to be the following table with columns 
VehicleName | StartDate | EndDate | TotalDistance | Duration (sum of durations between each startDate and enddate 
[image: Final Table]

Comment: i don't understand how you calculate `duration` at all. can you please elaborate?

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557

Comment: May we see what you have tried? Tip: It's helpful to tag database questions with both the appropriate software (MySQL, Oracle, DB2, ...) and version, e.g. `sql-server-2014`. Differences in syntax and features often affect the answers.

Comment: Diuration is a timer that run on mobile side. I convert the seconds into HH:MM format and insert it to the table. 

I have the answers below - thanks for looking into it guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A CROSS APPLY may be a good fit here.

However, I get 18:15 for ID 2 (the sum of 8:15 and 10:00).  Perhaps a typo/error in the original question, or additional logic is required.

I should note that the hours CAN exceed 24 just in case it spans multiple days.

```
Select A.*
      ,Duration = Format(IsNull(B.Seconds,0)/3600    ,'00')    -- Hours 00 - 99
                 +Format(IsNull(B.Seconds,0)%3600/60,':00')    -- Minutes
                 --+Format(IsNull(B.Seconds,0)%60     ,':00')  -- Seconds
 From  Distance_Travelled A
 Cross Apply (
              Select Seconds = sum(DateDiff(SECOND,'1900-01-01',Duration))
              From   Idling 
              Where  VehicleName = A.VehicleName
                and  TimeStamp between A.StartDate and A.EndDate
       ) B
```

Returns

[image]

Comment: Its a typo in the original question. Thanks for help

Comment: @SunnyGill Happy it helped.  Also glad to learn it was just a typo.

Answer (score 1):

Kind of nasty but you get the idea:

```
select
    dt.id,
    dt.VehicleName,
    dt.StartDate,
    dt.EndDate,
    dt.Total_Distance,
    substring(cast(convert(time,dateadd(millisecond,sum(datediff(millisecond,0,cast([Duration] as datetime))),0),108) as varchar),0,9) [Duration],
    case when substring(cast(convert(time,dateadd(millisecond,sum(datediff(millisecond,0,cast([Duration] as datetime))),0),108) as varchar),0,9) is null then 
        'no duration...'
    else
        'sum between ' + convert(varchar, dt.StartDate, 108) + ' and ' + convert(varchar, dt.EndDate, 108)
    end as [Duration]
from
    distance_travelled dt
    left join idling i on 
         dt.vehiclename = i.VehicleName and
         i.TimeStamp between dt.StartDate and dt.EndDate
group by
    dt.id,
    dt.VehicleName,
    dt.StartDate,
    dt.EndDate,
    dt.Total_Distance
```

Comment: I would nest the result of the query with only the `substring(cast(convert..` part and add the `CASE` statement at the top level. It would make for a slightly cleaner code. Kind of nasty, but you get the idea.

Comment: User John Cappaletti has it done more efficiently as well. But thanks - the left join would work for another example i was about to post - but won't because you have the answer.